# jQuery doesn't fire automatically on new created elements

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with a button , and when a user click that button , new `select tags` will be appear

That new `select` has the class 'selector', and there is a jQuery call on that call , but doesn't fire

## html code

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>
        <select class='selector'></select>
        <input type='button' value='new select' id='newSelect'/>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

## jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var options = "<option>Select Name</option>";
    options +="<option>Roma</option>";
    options +="<option>Milano</option>";
    $('#ul .selector').html(options);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ul').on('click','#newSelect',function(){
        $('#ul').append("<li><select class='.selector'></select></li>");
    });
});
```

​[check the code here please](http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/puUcp/12/)

Comment: `$(document).ready` only fires when the DOM is ready, not on newly created elements.

Comment: @Gavin i wasn't know that information , and so how can i make jQuery fire on new created elements?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do once you have added the new select element? You can look at the `live` event, which would add an 'click' event to each .selector that exists and any that is created in the future. i.e. `$('#ul input').live('click', function() { // add select });`

Comment: Also, noticed that you are doing `$('#ul').on('click', '#newSelect', function()` when really, you should be doing `$('#newSelect').click(function()`

Comment: i will see live events , thank you, u helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling the selector, indeed, only triggers at document load, and the dot should be removed from the new select-class, and the selector should be filled onclick.
So the new code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var options = "<option>Select Name</option>";
    options +="<option>Roma</option>";
    options +="<option>Milano</option>";
    $('#ul .selector').html(options);

    $('#ul').on('click','#newSelect',function(){
        $('#ul').append("<li><select class='selector'></select></li>");
        $('#ul .selector').html(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: yes for sure your code will work , but now always i can save the options on a global variable because i am using ajax alot and not a good thing if i save what ever i get from the server , right ?

Comment: You're right. So I've put it all in the same document ready function, and then the variable doesnt need to be global anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the dot in this line:

```
$('#ul').append("<li><select class='.selector'></select></li>");
```

to

```
$('#ul').append("<li><select class='selector'></select></li>");
```

If you want tot populate the select list like you do in the first, it could be done like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/puUcp/19/

Comment: i removed it , and still doesn't fire , you can try it in my jsFiddle

Comment: thank you , yes man it works , but i have got the same exact answer, up vote and thank you

Comment: Except mine was first ;) Never mind though, glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you simply need to clone the first select element (which is already) popuplated each time you want to add a new one. This would look something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ul').on('click','#newSelect',function(){
        $('#ul').append($("#ul > li:first-child").clone());
    });
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/DvD6k/)**.

However you should not do *exactly* the above because `$("#ul > li:first-child")` includes the button which has an `id` -- and `id`s should be unique in the DOM. Removing the `id` from the button would make things OK.

Comment: ok i got u , but can i understand that there is not standr way to make jQuery fire on new created elements?

Comment: @tottiroma: No, there is not. And even if there were, what is it that should fire when new elements are created? Definitely not the code that you tell jQuery to specifically execute on document load!

Comment: thank you man i have got an asnwer, up vote for you and you helpe me, thanks